# How can i display datetimepicker on an input focus that was create on the fly

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I create inputs using .append() method on the fly what I need to do is bring up the datetimepicker when a user click's on the input field.

Here is what I have done so far but it is not working for me

```
        $('.triggerOnPicker').on('focus', datetimepicker({
            timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            stepMinute: 5,
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            HourMin: 5,
            HourMax: 17, 
            minDate: 0

        });
```

How can I fix this code to display the datetimepicker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it I had to add datetimepicker code to my $.getJSON();

```
$.getJSON(

//handle the request code


).done(function(){

    $('.triggerOnPicker').datetimepicker({
        timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        stepMinute: 5,
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        HourMin: 5,
        HourMax: 17,
            minDate: 0
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so like this:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.triggerOnPicker', function() {});
```

Comment: this code did not work i get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: datetimepicker is not defined "   to make sure i did it correct i did the following $(document).on('focus', '.triggerOnPicker', datetimepicker({ }));